# Problema com caractere

Tags: scanf

Meu professor me introduziu a um método de desbugar scanf com caracteres , mas não me deu a explicação disso;

Qual é o significado deste "%*c"?

Answer (score 0):

A expressão `"%*c`significa: Ler e ignorar um carácter.

Exemplo:

```
char s[20];

int d;

scanf(“%19[^:-]%*c%d”, s, &d);
```

Ele lê até 19 carácteres no 's' e só para quando se tratar de dois pontos.

> Dê uma olhada nesse post: [What does %*c mean in C/C++ programming?](https://www.quora.com/What-does-*c-mean-in-C-C++-programming)